# How can I extract values that have opening and closing brackets with regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract `[[String]]` with regular expression. Notice how a bracket opens [ and it needs to close ]. So you would receive the following matches:

- `[[String]]`
- `[String]`
- `String`

If I use `\[[^\]]+\]` it will just find the first closing bracket it comes across without taking into consideration that a new one has opened in between and it needs the second close. Is this at all possible with regular expression?

**Note:** This type can either be String, [String] or [[String]] so you don't know upfront how many brackets there will be.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Do you want to obtain these strings as separate matches?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to explain that with 'matches'.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted and really quick. Could you use it in an answer so I can mark it? Now I need to explore what you did to make it work ;-)

Comment: I am using the regular expression in PHP. I thought regular expressions were universal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following PCRE compliant regex:

```php
(?=((\[(?:\w++|(?2))*])|\b\w+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4dgrma/1). *Details*:

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead (necessary to match overlapping strings):

  - `(`- start of Capturing group 1 (it will hold the "matches"):

    - `(\[(?:\w++|(?2))*])` - Group 2 (technical, used for recursing): `[`, then zero or more occurrences of one or more word chars or the whole Group 2   pattern recursed, and then a `]` char
    - `|` - or
    - `\b\w+` - a word boundary (necessary since all overlapping matches are being searched for) and one or more word chars
  - `)` - end of Group 1
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/vQuiF):

```php
$s = "[[String]]";
if (preg_match_all('~(?=((\[(?:\w++|(?2))*])|\b\w+))~', $s, $m)){
    print_r($m[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [[String]]
    [1] => [String]
    [2] => String
)
```

Comment: I upvoted and bought you a smoothie to show my appreciation. There is just one last thing, if you want to help me out. Is it possible that you could have [[String?]] and get String? back, but also if it was [[String?]?] the flavor would be String? and [String?]?. The question mark does not have to be there so [[String]?] should still work. To conclude, could it work with an optional question mark.

Comment: @Mark Please play with `(?=((\[(?:\w++|(?2))*\?*]\?*)|\b\w+\?*))` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/4dgrma/2). The point is to add `\?*` to match any zero or more occurrences of question marks at the locations where you expect them.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Now I am going to dive deep into how you pulled it off. Anyways thanks again.